# Cannot read property 'routeName' of undefined react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying use a custom component for my drawer layout. Below is my custom Drawer component:

**CustomDrawer.js:**

```
class CustomDrawer extends Component {

  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 1
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Page1')}>
              Page1
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 2
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Page2')}>
                Page2
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Page3')}>
                Page3
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Text>This is my fixed footer</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

CustomDrawer.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object
};

export default CustomDrawer;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
     paddingTop: 20,
     flex: 1
   },
   navItemStyle: {
     padding: 10
   },
   navSectionStyle: {
     backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
   },
   sectionHeadingStyle: {
     paddingVertical: 10,
     paddingHorizontal: 5
   },
   footerContainer: {
     padding: 20,
     backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
   }
});
```

Below is my **router.js**:

```
const mapNavigationStateParamsToProps = (SomeComponent) => {
  return class extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = SomeComponent.navigationOptions; // better use hoist-non-react-statics
        render() {
            const {navigation: {state: {params}}} = this.props
            return <SomeComponent {...params} {...this.props} />
        }
    }
}

export const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
 Home: {
   screen: Home,
  navigationOptions : {
     tabBarLabel: 'Home',
     tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
   },
 },
 MyCards: {
   screen: MyCards,
   navigationOptions : {
    tabBarLabel: 'My Cards',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />
  },
 },

},
 {
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
   animationEnabled: true,
   tabBarOptions: {
     activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
   },
 },
);

export const drawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
    MyCards: {
      screen: MyCards,
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
    },
    SearchUsers: {
      screen: SearchUsers
    },
    CardRequests: {
      screen: CardRequests
    },
    GetCard: {
      screen: GetCard
    }
  }, {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawer,
    drawerWidth: 300
  }

);

drawerNavigation.navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
};

export const AppNavigation = StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: Login},
    SignUpScreen: { screen: SignUp },
    Tabs: { screen: drawerNavigation},
    AddCard: { screen: AddCard },
    GetCard: {screen: GetCard},
    SearchedUserProfile: {screen: mapNavigationStateParamsToProps(SearchedUserProfile) }
  },
  {
   headerMode: 'screen'
 });
```

When I run the app I am getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'routeName' of undefined

I am using `routerName` in `CustomDrawer`. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Two questions. Is it routerName or routeName? Your code says routeName but your error says routerName. Also, where are your routed defined? Because your are navigating to 'Page1' but I don't see that defined.

Comment: It's routeName, I was just testing it out. Page 1 is dummy

Comment: I am getting the error as soon I open the app

Comment: I assume that you did `import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'` in your **CustomDrawer.js** or there is no misspelling on that one.

Comment: no its all good

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding:

```
 drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
 drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
 drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
```

The complete Drawer Navigator:

```
export const drawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
    MyCards: {
      screen: MyCards,
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
    },
    SearchUsers: {
      screen: SearchUsers
    },
    CardRequests: {
      screen: CardRequests
    },
    GetCard: {
      screen: GetCard
    }
  },{
      contentComponent: SideMenu,
      drawerWidth: 300,
      drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
      drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
      drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  });
```

Hope it helps